# What controls the height of a text field in Ext JS?

Tags: extjs

I've been trying to adjust the height of my combo field.  I have tried several different methods, including setting config properties on the combo and its container, tweaking css, and using css mixins.  So far, I have had no effect on the height of the combo.

I'm using Ext 6 and the Triton theme.

Specifically, I want the combo box (in certain situations) to look just as it does out-of-the-box, except less white space around the value in the textfield, thus making the label and textfield consume less vertical space.

Comment: In Triton, `.x-form-text-default` has `min-height: 30px`. That refers to the actual input element.

Comment: As @EvanTrimboli mention, it depend on the theme you are using, inside you need to adjust css for it

Comment: That's why I included my theme (Triton) in my post.  I created my own theme based on it, but I have not been able to find the right levers to pull to affect the text field height.  I don't know where to go with the css class that @EvanTrimboli identified.

Comment: It comes from theme-neutral/sass/src/form/field/Text.scss:

`min-height: $ui-height - vertical($ui-border-width);`

Comment: Thank you @EvanTrimboli.  I am almost there.  I have created new UIs for extjs-text-field-ui and extjs-label-ui.  Something is setting .x-form-trigger vertical-align to 'top' instead of 'center'.  Can you direct me to the right place to set vertical-align to 'center'?

Comment: s/center/middle/g in my above comment